# If the company name are the same as the "reserved words" name, can I build Active Directory?

Tags: domain, subdomain, local

For example, can a company that owns "local.com" or "interactive.com" in its domain name build Active Directory with that name?
Are any "reserved words" prohibited on subdomains?

Comment: Have you read the [best practices](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34981.active-directory-best-practices-for-internal-domain-and-network-names.aspx) regarding AD domains?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Yes, I read it.
What I'm trying to find out is if Microsoft's "reserved words" itself is used in the DNS name of the company, can it be an obstacle to build Active Directory?
If a company owns "network.com" on the Internet and wants to build an Active Directory within the company, is it safe to use the "reserved words" as is?
If you add a subdomain, it would be "local.network.com